# Find whether elements in an array are consecutive with respective to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sequence

I want to know if elements of array A are consecutive with respect to array B. For example

```
["9:00 AM", "9:30 AM", "10:00 AM"]
```

is consecutive with respect to

```
["9:00 AM", "9:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "1:00 PM", "1:30 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:30 PM", "3:00 PM", "3:30 PM", "4:00 PM", "4:30 PM"]
```

and

```
["9:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM"]
```

is not.

And if elements of array A are consecutive then return the index. For example

```
let all_appointments = ["9:00 AM", "9:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "1:00 PM", "1:30 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:30 PM", "3:00 PM", "3:30 PM", "4:00 PM", "4:30 PM"];
console.log(all_appointments.indexOf(["9:00 AM", "9:30 AM", "10:00 AM"]))
```

should print `0`

Comment: Do you have an attempt to show us? (This site is not a code-writing service.)

Comment: And the problem is? That only requires a `for` loop and an `if`

Comment: If the elements of array A are consecutive then wouldn't the index always return 0?

Comment: your expected output is not clear. please provide some more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foobar(a, b) {
    const g = "__t(T.Tt)__";
    return b.join(g).indexOf(a.join(g)) === 0 ? 0 : undefined;
}
```

EDIT: added sad kirby to reduce chance of false positives

Comment: Same as Ifaruki's answer, it can end up in false positives, for example with `a = ["a", "bc"]` and `b = ["ab", "c"]`.

Comment: @sp00m good point. I've modified the answer to decrease the likelihood of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

If the "reference array" cannot contain duplicates, this should suit your needs:

```
const indexOfArray = (needle, haystack) => {
  if (!needle.length) {
    return 0; // debatable
  }
  if (!haystack.length) {
    return -1; // debatable
  }
  const haystackOffset = haystack.indexOf(needle[0]);
  if (haystackOffset < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  for (let needleIndex = 1; needleIndex < needle.length; needleIndex++) {
    const haystackIndex = needleIndex + haystackOffset;
    if (haystack.length <= haystackIndex) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (needle[needleIndex] !== haystack[haystackIndex]) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return haystackOffset;
};
```

Example:

```
const haystack = ["9:00 AM", "9:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "1:00 PM", "1:30 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:30 PM", "3:00 PM", "3:30 PM", "4:00 PM", "4:30 PM"];

indexOfArray(["9:00 AM", "9:30 AM"], haystack); // 0
indexOfArray(["9:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM"], haystack); // 1
indexOfArray(["10:30 AM"], haystack); // 3
indexOfArray(["9:00 AM", "10:00 AM"], haystack); // -1
indexOfArray(["4:30 PM", undefined], haystack); // -1
```